# How to include multiple context elements in render()

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. My views.py file looks like this -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import twitterData

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    profiles = twitterData.getTwitterProfileData()
    return render(request, "blog/home.html", profiles)
```

This code works fine, profiles is simply a dict of user profile names gathered from Twitter api. Only thing is I want to put this also {"Title": "Home"}. This would allow the page to display the correct title.

I try and write the code like this -

```
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    profiles = twitterData.getTwitterProfileData()
    return render(request, "blog/home.html", {profiles, "title": "Home"})
```

and it doesn't run. How can I use multiple items to send to page?

Comment: Could you improve your question with errors ? Doesn't run means anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that contains all data you want to render in your view.

```
 def home(request):
     profiles = twitterData.getTwitterProfileData()
     context = {
        'profiles': profiles,
        'title': "home",
     }
     return render(request, "blog/home.html", context=context)
```

access it in your template like:
`{{ profiles }}` and `{{ title }}`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
return render(request, "blog/home.html", {'profiles': profiles, 'title': "Home"})
```

or you can use context as suggested before.